# populating a list in python via append

Tags: python, list, append

I am practicing beginners Python projects and trying to do the dice rolling simulator, where it stores the totals of all die in a list. However, it doesn't work for some reason. Could someone explain why a code like this works:

```
n=0
a=[]
while n<6:
    n+=1
    a.append(n)

print(a)
```

and produces [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], but this code doesn't:

```
import random
maxnum=6
minnum=1
roll_again="y"
count=0
while roll_again=="y":
    tots=[]
    print("rolling the dice...")
    roll1=(random.randint(minnum,maxnum))
    roll2=(random.randint(minnum,maxnum))
    count+=1
    total=roll1+roll2
    print(roll1, roll2)
    print("Try #",count, ": Total = ", total,"\n")    
    roll_again=input("Roll the dice again? Y/N    ")
    if roll_again!="y" and roll_again!="n":
        print("please enter 'y' for yes or 'n' for no")
        roll_again=input("Roll the dice again? Y/N    ")
    tots.append(total)

print(tots)
```

It just prints the last total as a list with one value. What am I missing here?

Comment: You reassign the list to be ```[]``` each iteration of the loop.

Comment: god i am stupid...thanks a lot for pointing this out!

Comment: No you're not. Just keep working ;)

Comment: as a side note, your `if ... != 'y' ...` could be a `while`, to assert a valid value from the user (keep asking until answer is `y` or `n`). (you probably also can use a `str.lower` to account for case issues, since the hint is `Y/N` but the expected answer is `y/n`)

Comment: I would probably use `roll_again = input(...).lower()` and `while roll_again not in ['y', 'n']:`

Comment: yes, i should try to transform the letters to lowercase as well, thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the `tots = []` out of while loop, as wnnmaw suggested. Write it just before the loop, underneath `count=0`.

Answer (score 3):

you reset the list `tots=[]` in each iteration so that it never gets to hold more than one element. try to put it outside the while loop:

```
tots=[]
while roll_again=="y":
    ...
    tots.append(...)
print(tots)
```